# How does Android Studio display an offline map using osmdroid and mbtiles

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid, mbtiles

We are working on an android app that has to display an offline map of one specific location (say 3-7 neighboring islands). We successfully displayed the whole world, but that is too heavy. And when the phone is offline, the map has limited zooming (becomes blurry and it starts lagging).

I envisioned the app to be like Maps.me, wherein if you're offline, you get continuous zooming-in of a downloaded map. Been trying to get my head around https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles and after 2 and a half days, I was able to get mbtiles using Maperitive.
But from there, I'm confused on what the next step is. From the github tutorial, I'm stuck here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles#using-offline-tile-archives
Does this mean I have to manually put the mbtiles to the path or is there a way to store and use the mbtiles automatically (or through code) ?

I just started learning about osm and android studio a few weeks ago and I need help. Badly. Someone please enlighten me.

Comment: By "a way to store and use the mbtiles automatically (or through code) " I meant: Is there a way that the mbtiles will be stored there when the app gets installed?

Comment: If the file is reasonably big, put the file into the assets directory. It will be part of apk and therefore installed with the application.

Comment: Do you really need to display offline maps in Android Studio as the title of your question states? Or do you mean you are implementing offline maps in your app?

Comment: @JosefAdamcik  thanks! Worked fine when I copied zoom-level folders of a total size of 2.40 MB. How would you implement this with gigabytes worth of tiles?

Comment: @sealion_cr Check spy's answer. First two options would suit you well for larger files.

Comment: @sealion_cr Since you are an android beginner, I would suggest going with the first option (hosting archive with tiles on some server and downloading them to the phone on the go). You'll learn how to download  a big file into your phone and how to work with it. On its own it is not a trivial task. But you may still find your files too big for this approach, so think about limiting the area, limiting the available zooms and/or splitting the region into more smaller regions.

Comment: @sealion_cr But the option 2 (CacheManager) is generally better, I think. You would have to serve your tiles primarily online and than implement the [CacheManager](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Cache-Manager). I feel it migh be a little bit more complicated, than the first one. But I actually don't have any personal experience with the CacheManager, so it's hard to judge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can host the tile archives on a server that your provide for your app's users to download
- You can use the CacheManager utility to enable your users to cache and/or permanently archive tiles for given area before going offline
- As mentioned by @Josef Adamcik, if the quantity of tiles is small, you can put them directly in `/assets/YourTileSourceHere`. Then tell osmdroid to use a map tile source matching that name
- If the tile archive is smallish, you can also put it in `raw` then on installation copy it out to somewhere osmdroid can read it, such as `/data/data/yourpackagename` (this is also known as app private storage OR copy to /sdcard/osmdroid or whereever you want, just use Configuration.getInstance().set.... methods to configure the path for it.

And if you have suggestions for improving the wiki, please let me know

Comment: I tried using tiles of a smaller area and it loaded fine after putting them directly to assets, so THANK YOU! But those were just mock up tiles. And the actual tiles that I'll use are GBs in size. Tried copying some of the zoom folders (total size: 179 MB) to assets and it takes so long to build the app. How can I use my tiles of large sizes?

Comment: large sizes is answered above, download the files separately within your app. There's a limit to much stuff you can put in an APK. Also a sqlite database will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to put the mbtiles file onto your phone and specify the correct path in your app code.